# Where I can find my PLPython functions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I've created some functions in a specific schema, but the "Functions" section has nothing inside..

I create functions like this example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer)
  RETURNS integer
AS $$
  if a > b:
  return a
return b
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code used for the function creation ?

Comment: `the "Functions" section` where? In pgAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name is not schema-qualified, a function (like other objects) is created in your current schema. Your current schema is defined by the current setting of [**`search_path`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

To see your current `search_path`:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

There are a number of ways to set the `search_path`, more in this related answer:
[How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

To find out whether any function with a similar name exists in your database:

```
SELECT n.nspname, p.proname, pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) As args
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  p.proname ILIKE '%pymax%';
```

If that doesn't find anything, the functions doesn't exist in *this* database. Maybe you created it in another db by mistake?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited answer to search in namespace. (I don't know functions name =D)